# cannot find image of webite header in joomla

Tags: joomla1.5

Am just beginning with joomla on a site that is already existing and was previously managed by someone else who is not available at the moment. I am trying to troubleshoot a problem why the website is displaying the header differently in different PCs but I am not being able to find the image of that header file. I tried to look for it under "site > media" but cannot find the image among the images in that area. I also tried to look for the path to the image through the template css and found this path `../images/logo.png` which I believe must be the path to the header image but I honestly don't really know which path `../images/logo.png` is but assuming it is the one under "media" then I still cannot find the image. Could you give me a clue on where the header image files could be found cause I've actually still failed? Or, could you make me understand this path `../images/logo.png` or how to find an image on a joomla admin interface like say "logo.png". In fact I discover that on looking at the CSS for the template, the image paths found in it are not found in "Media"? Is there another path for the images in the template and how do I access them? I cannot FTP my host at the moment to view the physical files due to the long procedure needed so am hoping that there is a way to find it. I only have joomla admin access and nothing like Cpanel as yet. The joomla version of the site is 1.5.22 which I know is an old one but I plan to do first things first. Hope I've given enough infor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using FireBug, or Chrome debugger - (press F12) and check "Click an element in the page to inspect" to see where the specific image is located exactly.

Comment: Thank @user189274. i've installed firebug and it shows that the path is "http://<mydomain-name>.com/templates/bluesoul-tg/images/logo.png". "bluesoul-tg" is the name of the template. This tells me that the path is in the template folder. The question is, is there a way I can access that path through the admin backend so that I can view it and maybe edit it?

Comment: Oh yes! That path from firebug is exactly what I wanted. I'm able to access the image directly, edit it and then through joomla administration interface I upload it and the changes are reflected. Thank you